# ALL RUNNING SERVICES (explanatory)

Tags: android, service, pid, activity-manager

I have tried to find a nice explanation about some *unsuspected* result in **getRunningServices**. This is a simple code to get a complete list of **all running SERVICES**:

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) myApp.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = actvityManager.getRunningServices(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++) {
    RunningServiceInfo service = services.get(i);
    Log.d("PROCESS= " + service.process, "PID: " + service.pid + " UID: " + service.uid);
}
```

Analyzing the results, I have noticed that there are one or more services with **PID=0** like *com.google.android.talk* and *com.android.bluetooth*. Also, there are **multiple instances** of services like *com.android.phone* and *com.google.android.gms*. Here is an example of the *LogCat*:

[image: All Running Services Log Result Example]

Obviously, if I want a real list of running services, I can **filter out** all repetitive instances and maybe filter out all services with PID=0. But before that, these are **my questions**:

**1.** Please, can someone explain to me why there are **multiple instances** of the same service in **getRunningServices**.

**2.** I have understood that any RUNNING process, application, service, has a given PID number, so, why **getRunningServices** gets running services with ***PID=0***?

Comment: In the other hand, listing all RUNNING APLICATIONS usin getRunningAppProcesses, its perfect. I dont understand getRunningServices results.